# Searching inline for a word vim

Tags: vim

Let's say I have a line like so:

```
setUp.then(() => process.exit())
```

Is it possible in vim to navigate to that line and start typing 'proc' and have it jump to process?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+incremental+search

Answer (score 0):

If "process" appears in only one line in your file, then vim search will take you to this very line.

```
/proc
```

If "process" appears in more than one line, then you can make your search a little specific (assuming the pattern `=> process` appears only one in your file), search instead with:

```
/=> proc
```